# Touchpad works on a Dell Inspiron M5030 but external mouse moves slow

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse

I have 12.04 32-bit installed in my M5030 Dell Inspiron. It has a AMD Turion™ II processor, an ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD4250, and 3GB in RAM.

I also had 11.10 and had the same problem. The Touchpad is fine, but the USB mouse doesn't work normally, it is very slow when moving. I tried changing it's velocity and installed new updates but nothing, still I can't get the mouse to work properly.

I really hope to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does it stutter, or is it just the sensitivity that appears very low?

You can try this solution if it's just insensitive. 
Run `xinput --list --short` and see if you can locate your mouse.
For example, my mouse listed looks like this:

```
SteelSeries World of Warcraft MMO Gaming Mouse  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

If your mouse is listed, you can try this:

```
xinput --set-prop "Your mouse name" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" X
```

and replace X with an integer somewhere between 1 and 10, where 1 is very insensitive.

For example, like you can see, I have the the MMO mouse from Steelseries. My command would look like this (my problem is, unlike yours, that the mouse is too sensitive)

```
xinput --set-prop "SteelSeries World of Warcraft MMO Gaming Mouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3
```

If this doesn't work, you can try replace the name with the id. If you notice changes, but it's slower or way too fast, you can experiment with different numbers. Like I mentioned above, the higher the number, the more sensitive your mouse becomes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, i've proved what you say changing sensitivity, but mouse still not working whit normally. I think the problem is with mouse driver or with xorg server configuration. Only Once time make run the mouse but ubuntu stops working in a few days and i had to reinstall my ubuntu, and i never knew if it work with the ubuntu software update or with some the xorg.conf file edition that make.